# JavaFX duplicated children added at remove

Tags: java, javafx, illegalargumentexception

I have a quite strange problem in javafx. If I add some rectangles to a anchorpane and delete them afterwards, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = AnchorPane

But now the real problem shows up: The exception is quite random.
So, I do not get the exception always when I delete a rectangle and that is what I do not understand. I already debugged everything, but there are no differences between a "no exception termination" and a "with exception termination" (I hope somebody can understand my weird writing xd)
Another problem is that I do not know how to reproduce this issue. It is to 100% my fault, but I cannot say what I am doing wrong.

Now my last try is to ask a question here. Does anybody has some tips for this exception?
(I am using the newest IntelliJ version and JDK17 + JavaFX 17)

Rectangle/Node Class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MyNode extends Rectangle {

    private int myNodeId;
    private SimpleStringProperty myNodeIdProperty;
    private DecimalFormat threeDigits;

    public MyNode() {

    }

    public MyNode(double xCord, double yCord, double width, double height, int myNodeId) {
        super(xCord, yCord, width, height);

        this.myNodeId = myNodeId;

        threeDigits = new DecimalFormat("000");

        this.myNodeIdProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.myNodeIdProperty.set(threeDigits.format(myNodeId));
    }

    public int getMyNodeId() {
        return myNodeId;
    }

    public void setMyNodeId(int myNodeId) {
        this.myNodeIdProperty.set(threeDigits.format(myNodeId));
        this.myNodeId = myNodeId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyNode myNode = (MyNode) o;
        return myNodeId == myNode.myNodeId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(myNodeId);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone sees already a weird thing in my node class. As you can see, I have a unique id and a property to bind this id to a tableview cell. I add and remove the nodes with the following code:

```
anchorPane.getChildren().add(myNode);
anchorPane.getChildren().remove(myNode);
```

I see forward to your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You don’t need your own [id](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#idProperty) property, all nodes have this already. Also your other custom field threeDigits is not used or exposed.  So it does not seem necessary to extend Rectangle here.

Comment: I know that every node has its own id already, but they are related with CSS and I want my own unique IDs.

Comment: I would consider overriding `equals` / `hashCode` for a `Node` subclass to be "wrong". Given how JavaFX works, whether or not a node is a "duplicate" should really be based on object identity. I don't know if that's related to your problem though; it would be best to provide a proper [mre] demonstrating the exception. But if that is related to your problem, I would recommend creating a model and refactoring out the ID (and maybe even the formatting) out to there. Then simply "map" your model objects to unique `Rectangle` objects (no need for subclassing).

Comment: You are right... I removed the overrides and now everything works fine. Thank you for your help. I wasted hours for that. I also CHANGED the equals method, but I did not try to remove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the overrides of the equals and hashcode methods... I removed them and now everything works fine. Thank you @Slaw.